# How to count the number of list elements embedded in a datafrane column?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, numpy

I have a dataframe that looks like the below (inclusive of the brackets and quotes):

| ID | Interests |
| --- | --- |
| 2131 | `['music','art','travel']` |
| 3213 | `[]` |
| 3132 | `['martial arts']` |
| 3232 | `['martial arts']` |

The desired output I am trying to get is:

| ID | Interests |
| --- | --- |
| 2131 | 3 |
| 3213 | 0 |
| 3132 | 1 |
| 3232 | 1 |

I've tried using

```
from collections import Counter
ravel = np.ravel(user.personal_interests.to_list())
```

But that just gives me the count of each combination i.e.:
['martial arts']:2

I've also tried stripping the quotes and using a series to count, but to no avail.

Comment: What is the output of `user.to_dict('list')` (assuming the DataFrame is named `user`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have lists (`['music','art','travel']`):

```
df['Interests'] = df['Interests'].str.len()
```

If you have strings (`"['music','art','travel']"`):

```
from ast import literal_eval

df['Interests'] = df['Interests'].apply(literal_eval).str.len()
```

Or, if you know that there are no quoted commas:

```
df['Interests'] = df['Interests'].str.count(',').add(df['Interests'].ne('[]'))
```

Comment: Thank you, it was the literal eval that does the trick for me! I guess the first one was just counting all of the characters, wheras the literal actually counted the words.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using **len()** method in Python

If **df** is your dataframe,

```
df['new_interests'] = df['Interests'].apply(lambda x: temp.append(len(x)))
```